# What is the ruling if we raised our leg against a closed cupboard

Tags: sin, shirk, kufr

Assalamualaikum ,

What is the ruling if we raised our leg against a low laying closed cupboard that has Islamic books in it , does it will be considered as kufr if we done it without an intention of disrespecting the books

**Is that will be considered as kufr?**

Please only mention it is kufr or not.

Comment: Please use meaningful titles to attract the right people to answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

Alsalam alikum brother/syster. The prophet [pbuh] said

> Actions are according to intentions, and everyone will get what was intended. Whoever migrates with an intention for Allah and His messenger, the migration will be for the sake of Allah and his Messenger. And whoever migrates for worldly gain or to marry a woman, then his migration will be for the sake of whatever he migrated for. [Source](https://40hadithnawawi.com/hadith/1-actions-are-by-intentions/)

So if you were inredning to do that act of kuffur then you have to repent and seek forgivness but if you didnt intend on doing it then inshallah it is not kuffur but try not to do it again and seek forgivness anyways, it is never wrong to seek forgivness.

Hope that answers your question.
Allah knows best.

Comment: Yes so in that case you repent and seek forgivness from ypur heart and inshallah Allah [swt] is all merciful and he will forgive you.

Comment: Brother i cant give you a definite answer because i dont know the whole story but what i can give you is that, in case you didnt mean then inshallah it is not kuffur and in case you meant it COULD be kuffur but either way Allah said in the holy Quran  "Say, ˹O Prophet, that Allah says,˺ “O My servants who have exceeded the limits against their souls! Do not lose hope in Allah’s mercy, for Allah certainly forgives all sins.1 He is indeed the All-Forgiving, Most Merciful." Quran 39:53 so just seek forgivness and Allah [swt] will inshallah forgive you.

Comment: No brother that is inshallah not kuffur. From what i understood is that you forgot that you had the books there and in that case we go back to the hadith which is every action is according to intention so from what i understood is that you didnt have the intention of disrespecting the books. Other then that not all Islamic books are holy books as long is it is not the quran then even if you meant to do it is okey inshallah.

Comment: Brother as i said before dont be scared and you being scares is inshallah a sign of piety, allah has inshallah forgiven you especially that you were sleepy and in that state a person dosnt have that much control over thier body so back again it was not intentional inshallah

Comment: As i said you didnt intend to disrespect the books so no it is not kuffur inshallah.